# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length

Tags: javascript

I am getting following error on my page. This is creating pages for slider:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length
    at populatePager (jquery.bxslider.js:608)
    at m.fn.init.el.redrawSlider (jquery.bxslider.js:1302)
    at resizeWindow (jquery.bxslider.js:1097)
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)
    at r.handle (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Here's my code:

```
   var populatePager = function(){
   var pagerHtml = '';
        var pagerQty = getPagerQty();
        // loop through each pager item
        for(var i=0; i < pagerQty; i++){
            var linkContent = '';
            // if a buildPager function is supplied, use it to get pager link value, else use index + 1
            if(slider.settings.buildPager && $.isFunction(slider.settings.buildPager)){
                linkContent = slider.settings.buildPager(i);
                slider.pagerEl.addClass('bx-custom-pager');
            }else{
                linkContent = i + 1;
                slider.pagerEl.addClass('bx-default-pager');
            }
            // var linkContent = slider.settings.buildPager && $.isFunction(slider.settings.buildPager) ? slider.settings.buildPager(i) : i + 1;
            // add the markup to the string
            pagerHtml += '<div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="' + i + '" class="bx-pager-link">' + linkContent + '</a></div>';
        };
        // populate the pager element with pager links
        slider.pagerEl.html(pagerHtml);
    }
```

Please suggest.

My purpose is to embed 4 youtube videos as slider items.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you showed a line number, or adjusted the line numbers in the error message to the snippet that you sent.

Comment: Question: Why are you using addClass inside a loop? And why are you checking the same condition in loop? It would better if you make the check outside the loop :)